# tinymce editor css issue inside the textarea joomla

Tags: php, css, tinymce, joomla2.5

i got a issue in tinymce editor , when i included the following  css file s

as sting with inside the textarea in the admin.comtent.html.php file . the text 
is retrieved from the database .

this is my code

```
$row->text .= htmlentities("<link href='templates/system/css/system.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />");
$row->text .= htmlentities("<link href='templates/tpl_safari/css/template.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />");

echo $editor->display( 'text',  $row->text , '100%', '550', '75', '20' ) ;
```

when i debug the `$row->test`  it shows the content from the database and also the css link , but in the editor the css is not applied , i have viewed it in the html source there the css is not applied , and also in the browser using firebug i edit that content and added the link there the css is now applied .

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add css this way to the editor.
Have a look at the tinymce configuration option [content_css](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3acontent_css) and how you can set this in joomla.